# Why isn't this package auto-updating?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, firefox, ppa

I have [the PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-daily/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) for Mozilla's daily builds of Firefox set up, but for some reason `firefox-trunk` has not updated for over a month.

In the PPA, it shows that it should be at version 45a1, but instead it's at 44a1. I've checked that the package isn't on hold:

```
↪ dpkg --get-selections | grep "firefox"
firefox                         install
firefox-locale-en               install
firefox-trunk                   install
unity-scope-firefoxbookmarks    install
```

And that there isn't another PPA that's giving me an older version:

```
↪ apt-cache policy firefox-trunk
firefox-trunk:
  Installed: 44.0~a1~hg20151017r268173-0ubuntu1~umd1
  Candidate: 44.0~a1~hg20151017r268173-0ubuntu1~umd1
  Version table:
 *** 44.0~a1~hg20151017r268173-0ubuntu1~umd1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I'm not sure what else to do. I need an updated version of Firefox, but somehow I've gotten stuck on 44a1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The straightforward answer is that the v45 series of builds are failing to be built - none of the builds for any series are available.

Also the v44 series of packages have been removed - hence the reason why you are left with that package.  It will not be updated until a newer package is correctly built.

Best look at the packages section of launchpad:

- https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-daily/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages

This will should you what packages are available with their build status.

As to why the failures occur - just click on the build status - buildlog link

[image: pic]

Remember that PPA is a test PPA - robotically built (mostly) by launchpad recipes... so no testing (or very little) testing would have been done.

More information probably can be obtained by contacting the PPA admins:

- https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-daily

Comment: Wow, frustrating, but thanks for figuring this out! Now I gotta find a better way to install nightly.